# homologically trivial $1$-cycles and surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth (complex) threefold and $\gamma\in {\rm CH}_1(X)$ a homologically trivial $1$-cycle. Is there a way to construct a (singular) surface $S\subset X$ supporting $\gamma$ such that, denoting $\tau:\widetilde S\rightarrow S$ a desingularization, there is a homologically trivial $\widetilde\gamma\in Pic^0(\widetilde S)$ satisfaying $$i_*\tau_*\widetilde \gamma =\gamma \ \ {\rm in\  CH}_1(X)$$
where $i:S\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion?

Comment: You mean $\gamma$ in $\mathrm{CH}^1(X)$ (codimension $1$)?

Comment: Thank you. No, I do mean "curves".

Comment: If you take any surface containing the curves in the support of $\gamma$, and take a resolution of it, you get a class in $Pic(\widetilde S)$ that pushes forward to $\gamma$ like you say. Is your question whether we can take this to be homologically trivial?

Comment: Indeed, my question is whether one can choose a class on $\widetilde S$ which is homologically trivial.

Comment: I suspect that this fails already for Hironaka's example, as described in Appendix B of Hartshorne's "Algebraic geometry".

Comment: For a projective example, simply take any cycle which is homologically equivalent to zero but not algebraically equivalent to zero. (On a surface, any 1-cycle which is homologically trivial is algebraically trivial.)